# sending a collection's items to some method as params[] vars

Tags: c#

I have a method `foo(params[] items)`

I have a collection (List, Set, ...)
I want to send its items to `foo` as items

what syntax can I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass array as only param it will be passed as items. So just use `Collection.ToArray`. Actually there is something good to know about when you're using `params`. If you pass null with intention to pass it as first and only param it will be used as null array. So with code like this:

```
SomeMethod(null);

public void SomeMethod(params object[] items)
{
...
}
```

Items will be null, not `array` with length of 1 and `null` as first elem.

Answer (score 1):

That method signature is invalid, so it won't compile. You still need to specify the type of the items, for instance:

```
foo(params string[] items) { }
```

then you can call it simply enough:

```
foo("one", "two", "three");
foo(new string { "one", "two", "three"});
foo(myCollection.ToArray());
```

Or,

```
foo(myArrayOfStrings);
```

Where `myArrayOfStrings` is an array of strings.

You should also be sure to check for a null argument prior to iterating the items, since,

```
foo(null);
```

is valid.